# How does this try-catch works?

Tags: java

The [Java code](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/command/coord/CoordSubmitXCommand.java#L334) I'm reading is:

```java
    private void validateCoordinatorJob() throws Exception {
        // check if startTime < endTime
        if (!coordJob.getStartTime().before(coordJob.getEndTime())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Coordinator Start Time must be earlier than End Time.");
        }

        try {
            // Check if a coord job with cron frequency will materialize actions
            int freq = Integer.parseInt(coordJob.getFrequency());

            // Check if the frequency is faster than 5 min if enabled
            if (ConfigurationService.getBoolean(CONF_CHECK_MAX_FREQUENCY)) {
                CoordinatorJob.Timeunit unit = coordJob.getTimeUnit();
                if (freq == 0 || (freq < 5 && unit == CoordinatorJob.Timeunit.MINUTE)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Coordinator job with frequency [" + freq +
                            "] minutes is faster than allowed maximum of 5 minutes ("
                            + CONF_CHECK_MAX_FREQUENCY + " is set to true)");
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Date start = coordJob.getStartTime();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(start);
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
            start = cal.getTime();

            Date nextTime = CoordCommandUtils.getNextValidActionTimeForCronFrequency(start, coordJob);
            if (nextTime == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid coordinator cron frequency: " + coordJob.getFrequency());
            }
            if (!nextTime.before(coordJob.getEndTime())) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Coordinator job with frequency '" +
                        coordJob.getFrequency() + "' materializes no actions between start and end time.");
            }
        }
    }
```

What I don't get is whether `"Coordinator job with frequency [" + freq + "] minutes is faster than allowed maximum of 5 minutes ("+ CONF_CHECK_MAX_FREQUENCY + " is set to true)"` log can be printed.

As long as I know, when `if (freq == 0 || (freq < 5 && unit == CoordinatorJob.Timeunit.MINUTE))` condition meets and the program throws IllegalArgumentException.
The thrown exception will be caught at `catch (NumberFormatException e)`, and handled in that block as `e`.

But that `e` is never used afterward.

So I wonder whether it's possible to print `Coordinator job with frequency ...` log.

For me, it doesn't seem to have a difference between the original code and just putting the catch block into `if (freq == 0 || (freq < 5 && unit == CoordinatorJob.Timeunit.MINUTE))` statement, as below:

```java
    private void validateCoordinatorJob() throws Exception {
        // check if startTime < endTime
        if (!coordJob.getStartTime().before(coordJob.getEndTime())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Coordinator Start Time must be earlier than End Time.");
        }

        // Check if a coord job with cron frequency will materialize actions
        int freq = Integer.parseInt(coordJob.getFrequency());

        // Check if the frequency is faster than 5 min if enabled
        if (ConfigurationService.getBoolean(CONF_CHECK_MAX_FREQUENCY)) {
            CoordinatorJob.Timeunit unit = coordJob.getTimeUnit();
            if (freq == 0 || (freq < 5 && unit == CoordinatorJob.Timeunit.MINUTE)) {
                Date start = coordJob.getStartTime();
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(start);
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
                start = cal.getTime();

                Date nextTime = CoordCommandUtils.getNextValidActionTimeForCronFrequency(start, coordJob);
                if (nextTime == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid coordinator cron frequency: " + coordJob.getFrequency());
                }
                if (!nextTime.before(coordJob.getEndTime())) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Coordinator job with frequency '" +
                            coordJob.getFrequency() + "' materializes no actions between start and end time.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @maloomeister The try statement also includes the if statement which throws the `IllegalArgumentException` the OP is talking about, not only the `Integer.parseInt()` statement.

Comment: However, it would not be caught for the reason @Sweeper stated above.

Comment: @Sweeper @DanielBarbarian Thanks. `NumberFormatException` is extending `IllegalArgumentException`, so I thought it would catch `IllegalArgumentException` too. Then, will it be okay to assume that the catch part is written for the case when `parseInt` fails, with invalid `coordJob.getFrequency()` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch catches a `NumberFormatException`, not an `IllegalArgumentException`, so it won't catch the the exception thrown in the `throw` statement. The fact that `NumberFormatException` inherits from `IllegalArgumentException` doesn't matter. `catch` clauses catch exceptions *down* the inheritance tree, not up. If a person can catch all `Tennisball`s, and you throw a general `Ball` at them, they would not catch it, would they?

Assuming that the other methods in the `try` clause doesn't throw `NumberFormatException`s, the `catch` clause is meant to catch the `NumberFormatException` thrown by `Integer.parseInt`.

> So I wonder whether it's possible to print Coordinator job with frequency ... log.

It could be printed by another method that catches the exception further up the call stack.